# Contornar o erro de duplicação de chaves primarias

Tags: sql, postgresql, script, sql-insert

Olá,

Tenho o seguinte script, .sql, para criar uma tabela e cria também um trigger.

```
SET client_encoding TO 'LATIN1';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION before_insert() RETURNS trigger AS '
  DECLARE
   n integer;
  BEGIN
   IF tg_op = ''INSERT'' THEN
     select count(*) into n
      from files
      where date=new.date and url=new.url;
      IF n > 0 THEN
        RETURN NULL;
      ELSE
        RETURN new;
      END IF;
   END IF;
  END
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create table files
    (date TIMESTAMP, 
     url VARCHAR(4000),
     type VARCHAR(100),
     status INTEGER,
     size INTEGER NOT NULL,
     arcname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (url,date));

CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON files
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE before_insert();
```

Pelo que percebo, a cada inserção verifica se já existe um registo igual, se existir não insere. 
Parece me que o trigger foi criado para a inserção não retornar o error de chaves primárias repetida. 
Já que tenho que inserir um valor de 90 milhões de registos e o trigger está a demorar muito tempo a responder a cada inserção, existe alguma outra forma para contornar o problema?

Obrigado.

Comment: Estude a cláusula ON CONFLICT do comando INSERT. Provavelmente a opção DO NOTHING possa atende-lo.

Answer (score 2):

A chave primária composta `(url, date)` da tabela `files` já é capaz de manter a integridade dos dados, essa `TRIGGER` é completamente desnecessária.

Porém, se a ideia é a inserção rápida e massiva de dados na tabela `files`, sugiro que todas as *triggers* relacionadas a tabela `files` sejam desabilitadas temporariamente da seguinte forma:

```
ALTER TABLE files DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

Para habilita-las novamente:

```
ALTER TABLE files ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

Se você tem certeza que a integridade dos dados que você deseja inserir na tabela `files` não violam sua chave primária, você pode acelerar o processo de inserção de dados removendo essa chave:

```
ALTER TABLE files DROP CONSTRAINT files_pkey;
```

Após as operações de `INSERT` você pode recriá-la da seguinte forma:

```
ALTER TABLE files ADD CONSTRAINT files_pkey PRIMARY KEY(url, date);
```

Comment: Mas acho que o trigger estava na tabela para quando se executa o script da inserção massiva não parar a execução com o erro da chave duplicada. Se fizer inserção massiva, contendo duplicação de chaves o script não dará erro e por consequência não termina a sua execução?

Comment: Alguma ideia de solução possível?

Comment: Seguindo a linha proposta por Lacobus você pode desabilitar a chave primária e as triggers, fazer a inserção massiva, verificar e tratar possíveis duplicatas e voltar a habilitar tanto a chave primária quanto o gatilho. Outra possibilidade é fazer isso em uma tabela auxiliar e depois de devidamente tratada copiar para sua tabela.